# OSPF unnumbered No ping between Switch and Vm possible

Tags: routes, ping, forwarding, icmp, ospf

I am trying OSPF Unnumberd and i have a VM (CentOs) and a Switch (Cumulus-Vx). When i try to ping from the Switch interface 1 to the Vm the Vm-Interface recieves the ICMP echo request but doesnt answer.
When i look into the forward routing table i dont see the other router but with vtysh i see it. THe Target Router is the 10.1.0.1

Routing table:

```
[root@centosone vagrant]# netstat -rn
Kernel IP Routentabelle
    Ziel            Router          Genmask         Flags   MSS Fenster irtt Iface
    0.0.0.0         10.0.2.2        0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
    10.0.0.1        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 eth1
    10.0.2.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
```

OSPFD table:

```
centosone# show ip ospf database 

       OSPF Router with ID (10.0.0.1)

                Router Link States (Area 1.1.1.1)

Link ID         ADV Router      Age  Seq#       CkSum  Link count
10.0.0.1        10.0.0.1         887 0x8000000d 0x3986 1
10.1.0.1        10.1.0.1         870 0x8000000f 0x1c9f 1

centosone# show ip ospf route
============ OSPF network routing table ============

============ OSPF router routing table =============
R    10.1.0.1              [100] area: 1.1.1.1, ABR
                           via 10.1.0.1, eth1

============ OSPF external routing table ===========
```

ICMP echo ignore all is set to 0.
Any idea what could cause this?
The Switch and the Vm have the Neighbor Status full.
OSI layer 1 and 2 are correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error Occurs when you dont have the 10.0.* as Loopback adress on your Loopback-Adapter